# What's the difference between broadcast a variable and pass as parameter in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink

In flink, to serialize variable to nodes, parameter could be passed as parameter in operator

```
env = ...map(new MapFunction(param))
```

and could also be broadcasted

```
dataset.map(...).withBroadcastSet()
```

actually `param` and `dataset` are both variables in program and does not have literal difference.

So what is actually the difference between these methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter and the MapFunction are initialized on Client's side and will be serialized to every task containing this MapFunction if you use parameter to pass the data.

And if you use broacast dataset, the broadcast data is sent through Flink's pipeline.

In another word, the difference is whether the broadcast data is serialized into task's deployment or not. If its size is very big, it'd be bad for the performance of deployment.

Comment: What is sent through Flink pipeline? Where is the data originally? Where is it after broadcasted?

Comment: @Litchy What do you mean? If you're using a HDFS file as the broadcast source, then it's originally stored on HDFS. And it depends on your implementation after it's broadcasted.